# What does this loss Curve tell me about the data?

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

currently i am working with LSTM and GRU Modells.
I applied them on a Multivariate Time Series Problem.

```
reset_random_seeds()
# design network weekly
model = Sequential()
#inputshape is using time stamps , feautures
model.add(LSTM(64,activation="relu" ,dropout=0.2, input_shape=(1, 19)))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=300, batch_size=258, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()

pyplot.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxzgM.png)

The Loss Validation looks like this and the results are pretty good to but i wonder what this graphs means to me.

Results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJpKY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXKIL.png)

Answer (score 0):

So at first this loss graph tells you how high the cumulated error for each example in your validation or training dataset is. So the loss value implies how good or bad your model is after each training iteration.

You loss graph shows us, that you have a much higher training loss than validation loss. This should be a good indicator, that your model at least might not be overfitting. On the other hand it also can be an indication, that your validation dataset might be very small or not that representativ. For example your validation dataset could be very skewed.

So we would have to look into your datasets a little deeper to fully interpret your loss graphes. If you can provide them I would be happy to have a look.

Comment: added the picture of the data above.
Also here is the link https://gyazo.com/64577a68be65eed3f78625031995b34a

Comment: Can you also tell us what you want to predict?
As of the picture you provided you can see a clear skew in the data from 2016 to 2017. Now an intresting comparison would be how the data of validation and the trainingsdata is structured?

Comment: yeah of course so i have weather data as exogen variables and the arrival data as the target varaiable and i want to predict the target variable with all the other data.

`reframed = series_to_supervised(lstm_df_w, 1, 1, dropnan=True)
values = reframed.values
n_train_weeks = len(train_set_weekly_multi)
train = values[:n_train_weeks]
test = values[n_train_weeks:]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
`
The split is 80/20

Comment: how do you split your data into train and test? can you provide your data preparation code in the question above for better understanding and readability?

Comment: yes so i split the data by 80/20 training data is 258 points and test data is 64 points.
The code is above.

Comment: yeah i see the code in the comment above...but with this i can't identify how train and test is structured. How did you split the data into train and test data.
Also do you use the testdata as validation and as test data?

Comment: yes i dont use validation data only train test.
I used the whole data set and splitted it into 80/20 so the first 80% of the data ist training and the second 20% is test.

Comment: Did you analyze the distribution of the target in train and test? 
Else without your data preaparation code and access to the dataset I'm just guessing which won't help you much.

Comment: Yes as u can see in the picture the data of the training set and the data of the test set is not quite the same in terms of distribution.

Thats why i also wonder why the results are so good as u can see in picture above.
https://gyazo.com/d6dc59f050b8d7af27c343536feaa022 --> screen of the dataframe

Comment: This picture doesn't really tell the whole story.
What  about the RMSE and other metrics of your model? 
How high is the loss and val_loss of the model? In your pictures the y_Axis shows like 800-1400.

Comment: the RMSE is pretty good with about 550 on the Test Set.